# Error when trying to Run the code, Range_Error(?)

Tags: codeblocks

I'm having this problem, my program compiles normally but when I try to run it the error 
"terminate called after throwing an instance of "Range_error" 
what(): Range error:0
 This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."

comes up. My code is the following, I'm using windows 8 and coding in CodeBlocks 13.12 with GNU GCC compiler.

```
> #include <iostream>  #include <vector>  #include <string>  #include "std_lib_facilities.h"
> 
> using namespace std;
> 
> class Name_pairs{
>         vector<string> name;
>         vector<double> age;
> 
>     public:
>         void read_names()
>         {
>         string control="yes";
>         int i=0;
>         while(control!="no")
>         {
>             cout<<"Insert a name "<<endl;
>             cin>>name[i];
>             cout<<"Do you want to introduce another name?"<<endl;
>             cin>>control;
>         }
>         }
>         void read_ages()
>         {
>             for(int i=0; i<=name.size();i++)
>             {
>                 cout<<"introduce an age for "<<name[i]<<endl;
>                 cin>>age[i];
>             }
>         }
>         void print()
>         {
>             for(int i=0;i<=name.size();i++)
>                 {
>                     cout<<name[i]<<", "<<age[i]<<endl;
>                 }
>         }
>         void Sort()
>         {
>             string tempn;
>             double tempa;
>             for(int i=0; i<name.size();i++)
>             {
>                 for(int j=i+1;j<name.size();j++)
>                 {
>                     if(name[i]>name[j])
>                     {
>                         tempn=name[i];
>                         tempa=age[i];
>                         name[i]=name[j];
>                         age[i]=age[j];
>                         name[j]=tempn;
>                         age[j]=tempa;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }; int main() {
>     Name_pairs List;
>     List.read_names();
>     List.read_ages();
>     List.Sort();
>     List.print();
>     return 0; 
>         }
```

Please if anyone could help :D Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if you could reduce the code to the minimum required to solve the problem.  Otherwise, this looks good.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>name[i];
```

You are assigning element `i` of vector `name` while `name` is empty
and has no elements. You can only assign `somevector[i]` if such an element exists. Do

```
string s;
cin >> s;
name.push_back(s);
```

to *add* a new element at the end.

(And BTW, you never increment `i` in `read_names`, so every the name
would be assigned to `name[0]`, overwriting the previous name, even
if element `name[0]` existed.)

Also, loops like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<=name.size();i++)
```

Are advancing `i` the Nth element of a vector that is N elements long.
The index of the last element is `N - 1`, so they overshoot the
vector. Should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < name.size();i++)
```

as you have in your `Sort()`